# excel: conditional formatting not working properly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I guess this is a question that has a stupid answer but I really couldn't fix this out.

I'm trying to make a hour comparison. I need to take any hour in column **D** and sum **11 hours** (or 0,458333333333333) and if this value is less than the hour in corresponding row in column **G** then the value inside the cell should be blue. If the opposite is true, then the value should be red.

Let's take row 8 as an example. I'm using these formulas below:

Red

```
=(D8+0,458333333333333)<G8
```

Blue

```
=(D8+0,458333333333333)>=G8
```

As the print shows:

[image]

And that had worked the first value I inserted on cell **G8**. As 12h is greater then 0h+11h (11h AM), it turned correctly blue. But when I changed the value to 8h, it doesn't turn into red as you can see below.

[image]

I was supposing that this would chande dynamically. I'm not very used with conditional formatting, so I'll appreciate any suggestion to fix this little issue.

Comment: Your examples don't work out - 8 AM (`08:00`) is less than 11 hours after midnight (`00:00`), so wouldn't `G8` be red?  11 Hours after midnight is 11:00, which is *greater* than 08:00.

Comment: @BruceWayne I got your point. But it turned correctly blue when I placed 12h and I thought that it would change to red when I placed the 8h (8:00 am), you know? But it didn’t happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your formula, you can use `TIME()` to make more logical statements.  Try this

For BLUE:

```
=$D5+TIME(11,0,0)<$G5
```

And for the rest, just format the color of the times in column G as Red. No need to use CF unless you really want to. If so, it'd just be

```
=$D5+TIME(11,0,0)>=$G5
```

Edit: Per @ScottCraner's excellent comment, you'll want to strip the integer day:

```
=MOD($D5+TIME(11,0,0)<$G5,1)
```

Comment: This will still create a number with an integer for the day.  You will need to strip the integer day to only get the time portion.

Comment: @ScottCraner how can I do that?

Comment: @paulinhax `=MOD(...,1)` where `...` is the formula above.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah! Thanks very much for pointing that out, I've edited it in to my answer.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks for that! although when I tried to use that, I got only 0:00 as an answer